# Solr : Search for implicitly related documents via shared fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr index to store and search articles. Each article has a mulivalued field to store Tags.
In our system Tags can be grouped and we call it Topic.So, there is another index to store Topics and each Topic has Tags.
Now the requirement is to search for the articles of a specific Topic. I know we can store Topic as A mulivalued field in the same index, but if there is any change in the Topic by adding or removing tags, we have to re-index entire articles.
I am wondering if there is a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLR is effectively a noSQL data store like MongoDB, Cassandra, *et al*.. so you have to embrace the noSQL mindset and discard RDBMS mindset...

So, I would just include them as additional multivalued fields, as you suggested and reindex everything when they change. Its a small price to pay and unless your indexes are really really big, I doubt re-indexing takes very long.

You'd have to re-index the secondary index anyway so it not much more work to re-index the primary index instead. That way you can discard the secondary index altogether (you should).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Article index will have hundreds of thousands of documents whereas Topic index will contain only hundreds. So rendindexing articles is a long process and I prefer to reindex Topic. But if there is no other way I have to include Topic inside article.

Comment: There ways around it... but they are hacks (IMHO). How often do the topic tags change and is it critical that they are updated straight away (or is it OK if there is a lag...)? You have to consider this and the extra code/complexity of adding this "relational" functionality/hack onto your SOLR system.

Comment: FYI, one of our indexes has 30 million documents, we update them all once a week for a similar reason but our data is stored in cassandra and we are used to the no SQL way of doing things. If indexing is taking a long time then you might want to look into ways of speeding up your indexing.